# Windows 10 IoT disable update

Tags: raspberry-pi2, iot, auto-update, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I would like to disable Windows 10 IoT update. I am using Rpi2 and 3. My app is running as default and I am using it for remote control of electronic devices. When the IoT is updating, app is not working and I need to have my app avalaible 24/7. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: So you want to be part of the next wave of IoT DDoS zombies? Just last week hacked IoT devices were used to launch a 620 GBps attack. Updates are the **ONLY** security measure available for IoT devices. You can't run firewalls, antivirus programs or install patches on an IoT device

Comment: I am using mobile data for internet connection. So I do not want to download large ammount of data.

Comment: Then don't use Insider builds. Data costs doesn't mean you should allow the device to be hacked. You'll pay a *lot* more if that happens. Did you encounter a real problem or did you assume that stable versions will receive large updates?

Comment: problem is that stable versions are updating from 10 minutes to 3 hours and 3 hours are quite long time

Comment: As long as you accept liability for the hacked devices and the communication cost for the attacks they launch ... You should probably check how to update more frequently, or apply security patches only, not close everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple. You have to stop and disable the update service. Both is done by PS script that is on this [website](https://brosteins.com/2016/09/06/disable-windows-update-windows-10-iot-core-powershell/)

Comment: Did you read the very big warning at the top that says *to never disable updates in production*? This answer is dangerous enough to warrant a downvote

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your response assumes the device has access to the Internet. I am looking at making a device which communicates on an isolated network with no access to the Internet, so an update from an external network is impossible.

Comment: @FluxIX tough luck then, your devices just got pwned. On the one hand, IoT devices are too weak to run firewalls, antiviruses or even use HTTPS. Updates are the *only* defense measure all of them can use. On the other hand, no matter what you do, that network will *NOT* be as isolated as you think. Your own laptop will have access to it for example. Remember Stuxnet. On the other hand you said "network". Even if you mean a wired network, it *won't* be isolated. All it would take would be to attach another computer to an Ethernet port

Comment: @FluxIX this is no joke by the way. I suggest you take the reputable IoT courses on Coursera or edX and check the security-related parts. The restrictions are rather sobering. Updates may be the *only* defence you have against hacking. Yes it's hard, yes disconnections, but that's why IoT isn't trivial and why the big cloud providers offer command, control, monitoring suites for them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the device would not have any access to the Internet as it is intended for deployment into a secure computing environment, so the monitoring and control machines are also on the same, isolated network (without access to the Internet). Yes, if other machines on the network were compromised the device could be compromised, but that posits there secure computing environment has already failed.

Comment: @FluxIX how does that affect anything? Business networks don't update Windows machines over the Internet, they use Update servers. Servers deployed on DNZs still get updated, in fact they get security fixes sooner than others. Even if you think you don't need to worry about security, you still need to update and deploy your own software. Will you go to each individual machine with a USB stick? This isn't a "Yes but". It's an actual restriction of the IoT domain, no matter the deployment environment.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the software is loaded before device installation; physical access to the device requires special access.

Answer (score 0):

Go to  control panel -> administrative tools -> services

try to find windows update 
double click on it select disable
if you don't understand watch this video 
https://youtu.be/QdYQ_9qmm8U

Comment: This solution is not for Windows 10 IoT Core.